# Regular Expression Match With Unintended Effects

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my first JS To Do List, and am running into an issue.

I've already created a To Do List App that can create, edit, and save a list of to do items.
I'm currently trying to create a program that imports an existing list and parse out the text so that it can be passed back into my To Do List Program (basically my first To Do List program will acknowledge a previously saved list as to do items and append them to whatever the user chooses to add).

I've used regular expressions at one point in the program to separate the words of the To Do List and to omit the numbers.  But surprisingly the function utilizing said regular expression has also omitted small short words like 'a' and 'to'.

I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, so I've probably not searched using the proper criteria for this issue.  Nevertheless, if someone could please help in pointing me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Below is the code:

```
/* Sample Document to be loaded: list7.txt
------------------------AM------------------------------
Meet Ann Ramon at 06:01AM
Build a Skyscraper at 10:10AM
--------------------------PM----------------------------
Talk to Roark at 08:09PM
Have Drinks at 08:30PM
Eat Steak at 11:12PM
*/

const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const fs = require('fs');

function readFile() {
    let wantFile = prompt('Would you like to import your List file?: ');
    if (wantFile == 'y' || wantFile == 'yes' || wantFile == 'Yes') {
        let fileRead = prompt("What's the name of your List file?: ");
        let readIt = fs.readFileSync(fileRead + '.txt', 'utf8');
        return readIt;
    } else {
        console.log('No List file imported');
    }
}

let fileSplit = readFile().split('\n');

(function removeAMPMLines(arr) {
    for (let i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].includes('at') == false) {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr[i]), 1);
        }
    }
})(fileSplit);

console.log(fileSplit);

/*

when loading my file list7.txt, it parses out the info and returns this:

['Meet Ann Ramon at 06:01AM',
 'Build a Skyscraper at 10:10AM',
 'Talk to Roark at 08:09PM',
 'Have Drinks at 08:30PM',
 'Eat Steak at 11:12PM']

so far, so good, but next we'll be removing ' at '
and sending the numeric values to another array.

*/

const splitArrWords = [];
const splitArrNums = [];
const splitArrAMPM = [];

(function splitEm (arr, arr2, arr3) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr2.push(arr[i].match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g)); //this is what I think needs to change, `but am unsure how.`
        arr3.push(arr[i].match(/\d/g))
    }
})(fileSplit, splitArrWords, splitArrNums);

console.log(splitArrWords);

/*
And this is where the interesting behavior comes in, this returns:

[
 ['Meet', Ann', 'Ramon', 'A', 'M'],
 ['Build', 'Skyscraper', 'A', 'M'],
 ['Talk', 'Roark', 'P', 'M'],
 ['Have', 'Drinks', 'P', 'M'],
 ['Eat', 'Steak', 'P', 'M']
]

so what happened to the 'a' in 'Build a Skyscraper', and 'to' in 'Talk to Roark'?

*/
```

Comment: Your regex only matches words that start with a capital letter

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse free-form text is futile. Save your file in a machine-readable format like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a regular expression with two groups, the note and the time. The time has a strict pattern `(\d+:\d+[AP]M)` the description may be any single line text. Lines that don't match this pattern are ignored.

Se the results below

```js
const txt = 
`------------------------AM------------------------------
Meet Ann Ramon at 06:01AM
Build a Skyscraper at 10:10AM
--------------------------PM----------------------------
Talk to Roark at 08:09PM
Have Drinks at 08:30PM
Eat Steak at 11:12PM`


function parseList(txt){
  const re = /([^\n]*) at (\d+:\d+\s*[AP]M)/img;
  
  const items = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    match = re.exec(txt);
    if(match){
      items.push(match.slice(1));
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return items;
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + 
  JSON.stringify(parseList(txt), null, 2) + '</pre>';
```